# Entity validation before the "beforeSave" RepositoryEventHandler fired

Tags: spring, validation, spring-data-rest

The [Spring Data REST docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/) describe the way to validate entities *after* the `RepositoryEventHandler` has fired:

> you simply need to register an instance of your validator with the
>   bean whose job it is to invoke validators **after** the correct event

Is there a way to apply [declarative] JSR-303 validation of entities *before* they get passed to the "beforeSave" `RepositoryEventHandler`s?

From what I can see so far debugging, that is not the case and the "beforeSave" `RepositoryEventHandler`s get fired before any validation takes place.

I can write validating calls in the handlers directly, but that would be different from how the "after" validation is handled.

Btw. the sequence of event handler calls seems to have changed between Spring Boot 1.3.8 and 1.5.1. In the past, the validation occurred *before* the `@HandleBeforeSave` handler. In the 1.5.1 `ValidatingRepositoryEventListener` fires *after* the `@HandleBeforeSave` handlers.

Update:

As mentioned in the comments, there seems to be a [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-685) in Spring Data REST Jira is open about this.

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround:

1. Create `PreflightValidatingRepositoryEventListener` which extends `ValidatingRepositoryEventListener` and annotate it with `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`.

   ```
   @Component
   @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
   public class PreflightValidatingRepositoryEventListener extends ValidatingRepositoryEventListener {
       public PreflightValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ObjectFactory<PersistentEntities> persistentEntitiesFactory) {
           super(persistentEntitiesFactory);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add same validators as for `ValidatingRepositoryEventListener`

   ```
   @Configuration
   @Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
   public class Config extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

       @Bean
       @Primary
       public Validator validator() {
           return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
       }

       @Autowired
       private PreflightValidatingRepositoryEventListener preflightValidatingRepositoryEventListener;

       @Override
       public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingListener) {
           Validator validator = validator();

           validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", validator);
           validatingListener.addValidator("beforeSave", validator);

           preflightValidatingRepositoryEventListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", validator);
           preflightValidatingRepositoryEventListener.addValidator("beforeSave", validator);
       }
   }
   ```

> NOTE: Validation will be ran twice

Comment: Thank you! Seems to be a neat workaround. My validation may not run after event handler. So I ended up with a good old aspect: http://scottfrederick.cfapps.io/blog/2012/03/09/Spring-3-Validation-Aspect

Comment: I was dealing with this today. My first success was the way I proposed here, but then I wanted to just make an aspect to add @Order to ValidatingRepositoryEventListener, but with no success. Can you share what you came up with?

Comment: Sure, shared it in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative workaround, here is an validation aspect fully based on [this](http://scottfrederick.cfapps.io/blog/2012/03/09/Spring-3-Validation-Aspect) example (with minor changes). Don't forget to add `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` to activate the aspect and put it into package that is scanned for Spring config.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class RestRepositoryValidationAspect {

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.HandleBeforeCreate)")
    private void beforeCreateInvocation() {
    }

    @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.HandleBeforeSave)")
    private void beforeSaveInvocation() {
    }


    @Around("beforeCreateInvocation() || beforeSaveInvocation()")
    public Object validateBeforeRepostioryEventHandler(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        Method method = methodSignature.getMethod();
        Annotation[][] argAnnotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
        String[] argNames = methodSignature.getParameterNames();
        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
          if (hasValidAnnotations(argAnnotations[i])) {
            validateArg(args[i], argNames[i]);
          }
        }

        return joinPoint.proceed(args);

    }

    private boolean hasValidAnnotations(Annotation[] annotations) {
        if (annotations.length < 1) {
            return false;
        }

        for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
            if (Valid.class.isInstance(annotation)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void validateArg(Object arg, String argName) {
        BindingResult result = getBindingResult(arg, argName);
        validator.validate(arg, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            throw new RepositoryConstraintViolationException(result);
        }
    }

    private BindingResult getBindingResult(Object target, String targetName) {
        return new BeanPropertyBindingResult(target, targetName);
    }

}
```

The repository event handler parameters that needs to be validated must be marked with `@Valid` annotation, e.g.

```
@HandleBeforeSave
public void handleSave(@Valid MyEntity myEntity) {
    ...
}
```